# how to redirect a button to calendar properties and fill the text box with the selected date in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar

[image]

Hello i really need your help regarding the image as attached. I'm using vb.net. I want to do something like the image. The first step is user will click the button after that, the Calendar will visible and user will pick the date and date will fill in the text box. I dont want to use the basic date picker.

What should i fill inside this code ?

```
Protected Sub Calendar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalendar.Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a Calendar control on your form. Also a button, and text box. This code will make the calendar appear when the button is pressed. When the calendar date is chosen, the calendar will disappear and put the date in the text box.

```
Protected Sub Calendar1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Calendar1.SelectionChanged
    TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()
    Calendar1.Visible = False
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Calendar1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit Calendar Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx).

You can use it like this:

Markup:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgPopup" ImageUrl="images/calendar.png" 
                 ImageAlign="Bottom" runat="server" />
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="Calendar1" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" runat="server" 
                      TargetControlID="txtDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

As you can see the `CalendarExtender` simply wants to know what server control (`txtDate` text box in this case) to use as the display of the date selected from the calendar control and what button (`imgPopup` image button in this case) triggers the popup of the calendar. You can also control the format of the date. Beyond that the extender control does the rest.

Note: In this example, the text box is made read-only, thus forcing the user to click the calendar popup to select a date. This may or may not fit your needs; so if you want the user to be able to type directly into the text box, then remove the `ReadOnly="true"` attribute from the text box control.